# admob library sync failed

Tags: gradle, admob

[show my problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcJM8.png)

I am trying to use the new Android Studio but I can't seem to get it working correctly. many try but not solve. please help me. admob library is not syncing in android studio.
Can anyone help? This is the first time I've used it. Thanks in advance.